# Find a number by counting cells except there are multiple reps with different lengths in excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to count the number of cells to find a value to insert into another worksheet. I have multiple reps with different lengths. For each position there are a certain number of markers. For the first line, if the position = 2, I need to count 2 markers into the position 2 group and would = Xbarc152. I will need to do this for each position and marker. The examples are in the first 5 columns and the library of data to search from is in columns 7 - 10. Here is my example: 
The data can be found in this link in a csv file from OneDrive, the data is hard to import so it can be worked with, so I figured a link would be a good option. The 8th column contains the data for the number of markers for each position so position 1 =58 marker, position 2 = 45 markers etc.

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgEoOOvNd3o3h6Y7k7TCXkG-fJbSug

Comment: Could you expand on where the 152 comes from plz?

Comment: The 152 is just part of the name of the marker

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, try:

```
E2: =INDEX(Marker_name,MATCH(C2,Position,0)+D2-1)
```

where `Marker_Name` and `Position` are named ranges referring to the used ranges in columns `I:J`.

*If for some reason you need to know how many are in each position, merely use the `COUNTIF` function*

[image]